# Since the new version of MRTK i cant build a scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

Since i use the new version of MRTK, i get that building error (Unity 2018 3 12f1). How can i fix that?
I had no issues with the old version, but in the old version i couldn't disable the spatial mesh render so it would disappear in my app.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgOtv.jpg

The other solution would be, to get the spatial mesh render disabled in the old version. So i dont need the new version. But i cant find the menu for that option.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4AQR.jpg

The only way to find the script is to search for "spatial", but that script is greyed out.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKmaW.jpg

PS: I'm new to this, so please explain it for a beginner.

Comment: Hi Leon, thanks for posting the question! FYI, I think you can directly copy / paste images without needing to link to imgur.

Comment: Hey, i tried that and it didn't work, but maybe i did something wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

From the first image you shared, it looks like you need to install the Windows 10 Insider SDK (version 18362 or later). The insider version of the Windows SDK has a few new classes that you need in order to compile for UWP.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewSDK

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, that helps alot. 
But if i understand that correct, i need a windows 10 insider Preview for the SDK version 18362. 
Is there a way to disable the spatial mesh render in the older version of MRTK?
i don't want to install the Windows Insider Preview because i'm working on my primary maschine.

Comment: Hi Leon, we are working on updating MRTK to not require Windows Insider Preview SDK, here is the bug: https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/3801

Answer (score 0):

okay, i found a way.
For anyone who has also problems with this:
https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/3898#issuecomment-481618334